# PHP not catching data from contact form (.htaccess?)

Tags: php, html, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been searching high and low on the net after a solution to my problem. I hope you guys can help me. I've read several posts on stackoverflow concerning .htaccess but I haven't found any of them to help yet.

On my website(my first, it's a learning process), [timeforyou.tk](http://www.timeforyou.tk/contact.html), I have a contact form (contact.html) that directs to process.php (in the same folder) where it is supposed to be handled - values taken out and then sent by email. However, the $_REQUEST array seems empty and I'm suspecting something with the .htaccess. My abilities in php are very low and I don't know what to write in .htaccess.

**Is .htaccess the problem and how do I edit it to work?**

Code1 (contact.html):

```
<form id="formContact" action="process.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                <!--Get or Post-->
                <ul>
                    <li><label>Company<br> <input type="text" name="company" id="company"></label></li>
                    <li><label>Name<br> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></label></li>
                    <li><label>Email *<br> <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></label></li>
                    <li><label>Confirm email *<br> <input type="text" name="email_confirm" id="email_confirm" title="emails don't match, please try again"></label></li>
                    <li><label>Message *<br> <textarea name="feedback" id="feedback"></textarea></label></li>
                    <li style="text-align: right;"><input type="submit" value="Send message" name="submit1" id="submit"></li>
                    <li>* Mandatory fields</li>
                    <!--onfocus="this.value = ''--> 
                </ul>
            </form>
```

Code 2 (process.php):

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
/*
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    //To timeforyou
    $company = $_POST['company']; //company name of author
    $name = $_POST['name']; //name of author
    $from = $_POST['email']; //email of author
    $msgToAdmin = $_POST['feedback']; //message from author
    $timeforyou = 'admin@timeforyou.tk';
    $subject = $_POST['company'];
(...)
}
*/
?>
```

I have been trying different things, and before **print_r($_REQUEST);** would just display **Array()**. Now, however, not even that happens; instead I just get redirected to error404.000webhost.com/?

.htaccess:

```
 # Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
    RewriteBase /

    # supress php errors
    php_flag display_startup_errors off
    php_flag display_errors off
    php_flag html_errors off

    # enable PHP error logging
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_value error_log /home/a3786788/public_html/logs/PHP_errors.log

    # prevent access to PHP error log
    <Files PHP_errors.log>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
    </Files>
```

I tried getting error logs by following this [site](http://perishablepress.com/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-htaccess/), but it does not seem to work (log does not get updated).

Please help, someone.

Comment: make sure process.php has executable permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not your .htaccess file.
Remove enctype="text/plain" from your form.
PHP does not handle it.

Comment: Removing enctype="text/plain" did the trick! My .htaccess now looks as follow (practically unchanged):     # Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
    RewriteBase /. In other words, .htaccess was not the problem; enctype="text/plain" was. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a .htaccess for a normal form. The page "error404.000webhost.com" looks like the default error 404 document. For example: http://www.timeforyou.tk/test1234.html Redirects also to "error404.000webhost.com".

Maybe u have a typo in filename ? proccess.php ? proccess.php.html ?

http://www.timeforyou.tk/process.php -> Redirects to "error404.000webhost.com".

Remove the .htaccess file. Maybe RewriteBase "/" is wrong.

Comment: It worked! I both removed .htaccess and "enctype text/plain". I'll check which one did the job before I choose what answer to accept. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't handle this enctype *text/plain*.

Check: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33741

> Valid values for enctype in  tag are:
>
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> multipart/form-data

The first is the default, you don't even need to write it down. Ssecond one you need only when uploading files.

Comment: It worked! I both removed .htaccess and "enctype text/plain". I'll check which one did the job before I choose what answer to accept. Thank you!!!